# CSV Files and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I assume this is a trick question on this hw i'm working on but maybe it's not?

What object do you get after reading a csv file?

data frame

character vector

panel

all of the above

From what I know, you can use pandas to read in a csv file into a dataframe. But i know a panel is a data structure in pandas too...character vector I've never even heard of.

Any one got any ideas? I'm fairly certain the answer is just dataframe, but hey never know.

Comment: Does the homework specify using pandas? Either way, you can answer this question yourself by firing up a python interpreter and opening a csv file.

Answer (score 1):

The time when you read a CSV file into a variable it is stored as a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` object which you are familiar of.

Now, talking about `Panel`, which represents wide format panel data, stored as 3-dimensional array have been deprecated since version 0.20.0 as listed [Pandas Panel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Panel.html).